# cant execute python script from php

Tags: php, python, linux, exec, shell-exec

here is my code in control.php:-

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("/var/www/script.py");
?>
```

why i cant run the shell_exec() command when i run the php script..? it should call the script.py and execute the py script.. but, when i run the control.php script..

note that i tried to run a normal program by using php where i tried to open gedit by using the command below:-

```
 <?php exec('gedit');?>
```

the gedit is not executed..

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is because of the php doesnt have the permission to write/read the py script in desktop.. so, just change the directory of the py to the same directory as the php file then eveything runs smoothly..

Answer (score 1):

Can you run "/var/www/script.py" in the BASH? if NOT, then check the script,make sure contain the following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

then chmod +x script.py to make sure it is executable.

Comment: i can run the  "/var/www/script.py" in the bash very well =) but not from the php itself..

Comment: have you disabled the selinux? the /var/www/script.py is usually a default folder for apache, you could run "getfacl" to check if the PHP interpreter has enough access to that script.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify `python` in `shell_exec()` explicitly:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /var/www/script.py")
```

or

```
$output = shell_exec("python /var/www/script.py")
```

and you need to ensure that your `script.py` has a permission better than `"-rwxrwxr-x"` as your php probably is executed by a different user.

Comment: both cannot be run.. i may need a permission.. but how to get the permission and how to know which user is executing the php? i run the code using google chrome in linux..

Comment: @ShahAbdHafiz You type `ls -ltr /var/www/script.py` and then the first column you get is its permission

Comment: solved! it just doesnt have permission to run the write/read to py script in desktop.. i changed the directory to the same directory of the php.. everything runs smoothly.. thank you guys!